# Cómo puedo agregar el index al li que se crea y mostrarlo dentro de la etiqueta li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como puedo agregar el index del li al li que se crea y mostrarlo dentro de la etiqueta li cada vez que se elemento.

El código de Jquery me implemente me crea los li con el texto ---> elemento, pero cada vez de que creo una li debe de mostrar lo siguiente:

- Elemento 0
- Elemento 1
- Elemento 2
- ...
- Elemento n-1

Pero ahora mismo se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código:

```js
// escribe tu código acá
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    insertarElemento();
  });

  function insertarElemento() {
    $('.elements').append('<li>Elemento');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul li.marked {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

button#add {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <h3>Elementos:</h3>
    <ul class="elements">
    </ul>
    <button id="add">Agregar elemento</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadir el número al `li` contando el número de `li` existentes con un simple selector de jQuery combinado con el `length`, algo como esto: `$(".elements li").length`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
// escribe tu código acá
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    insertarElemento();
  });

  function insertarElemento() {
    // le tienes que sumar length + 1 o empezaría en 0
    $('.elements').append('<li>Elemento ' + ($(".elements li").length+1));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul li.marked {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

button#add {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <h3>Elementos:</h3>
    <ul class="elements">
    </ul>
    <button id="add">Agregar elemento</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Otro modo de hacerlo sin necesidad de cambiar tu código JavaScript existente, sería usar los [contadores (`counter`) de CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). El contador se inicializaría para `.elements` y se incrementaría con cada `li`. El CSS relacionado como éste:

```
.elements {
  counter-reset: elementos;
}

.elements li {
  counter-increment: elementos;
}

.elements li::after {
  content: " " counter(elementos);
}
```

Que añadido en tu código funcionaría así:

```js
// escribe tu código acá
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    insertarElemento();
  });

  function insertarElemento() {
    $('.elements').append('<li>Elemento ');
  }
});
```

```css
.elements {
  counter-reset: elementos;
}

.elements li {
  counter-increment: elementos;
}

.elements li::after {
  content: " " counter(elementos);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul li.marked {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

button#add {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <h3>Elementos:</h3>
    <ul class="elements">
    </ul>
    <button id="add">Agregar elemento</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aunque dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer luego con los elementos, éste método puede no ser muy práctico.

Comment: Eso era lo que necesitaba, me pareció más práctico el cambio del código de Jquery.